# How can I grep complex strings in variables?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, if-statement

I am trying to grep for a small string in a much larger string. Both strings are being stored as variables and here is a code example:

```
#!/bin/bash

long_str=$(man man)
shrt_str="guide"

if grep -q $shrt_str $long_str ; then
        echo "Found it!"
fi
```

I don't think variable expansion is working the way I expect it to. I have tried `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`, also quoting the variables and piping the output to `/dev/null` but no matter what I do it won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/748724/pass-a-large-string-to-grep-instead-of-a-file-name | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/grep-on-a-variable

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
if echo "$long_str" | grep -q "$shrt_str";then
  echo "found"
fi
```

or

```
echo "$long_str" | grep  -q  "$shrt_str"  && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

But since you are using bash shell, then use shell internals. No need to call external commands

```
shrt_str="guide"
case "$long_str" in 
   *"$shrt_str"* ) echo "Found";;
   * ) echo "Not found";;
esac
```

Comment: Nice. The above case statement should be valid in the original `sh` too.

Comment: @ghostdog74 Best example of how to grep a string (rather than file) that I've found online. Thanks

Comment: Better call external commands, you get less dependent on the shell.

Comment: This doesn't work on Solaris 9 for me. But this works:

`echo "$long_str" | grep ``cat -`` "$shrt_str"` 

(I am sorry for the double backtics, haven't managed to escape them in any other way).

Answer (score 24):

grep is for files or stdin. If you want to use a variable as stdin then you need to use bash's herestring notation:

```
if grep -q "$shrt_str" <<< "$long_str" ; then
```

Answer (score 9):

You want

```
if echo $long_str | grep -q $shrt_str; then
```

Answer (score 9):

Another Bash-specific technique:

```
if [[ $long =~ $short ]]    # regex match
then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

But if you don't need the long string in a variable:

```
if man man | grep $short; then ...
```

but I'm assuming that was just for the purpose of having an example.

Comment: I tried the =~ solution but it didn't work. Nor does the test man page include the "~" as an operator.

Comment: `=~` is not a `test` operator, it's a Bash operator (note the double square brackets). It also works in ksh and zsh.