# bash: find string in multiple other strings

Tags: string, bash, list, search

I'm trying to use bash to find if a short string is present in any string "sets".
For example,

```
FRUIT="apple banana kiwi melon"
VEGETABLE="radish lettuce potato"
COLOR="blue red yellow green brown"

MY_CHOICE="kiwi"
MY_CHOICE_GROUP="?"
```

How can I set `MY_CHOICE_GROUP` to `FRUIT`?

I tried to use [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2106553/547398), but it only works with a single string set.

Originally, I was using arrays to store the options in a set, but [given the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value) [bash handles iteration over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396740/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-in-an-array-without-iterating-over-the-elements), it seems a string search would be more efficient.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the sets 'given' (unchanging)?

Comment: Yes, they are given (they won't change).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The simplest way, IMO, would be to just hardcode a bunch of `case...esac` labels.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   function lookup()
   {
       case "$1" in
           apple|banana|kiwi|melon)
               echo "FRUIT"
               ;;

           radish|lettuce|potato)  
               echo "VEGETABLE"
               ;;

           blue|red|yellow|green|brown)   
               echo "COLOR"
               ;;
       esac
   }

   MY_CHOICE="kiwi"
   MY_CHOICE_GROUP=$(lookup "$MY_CHOICE")

   echo $MY_CHOICE: $MY_CHOICE_GROUP
   ```

   See it **[live on ideone](http://ideone.com/rBdyaH)**
2. Otherwise, consider associative arrays, see it **[live on ideone](http://ideone.com/THsjaL)**:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   declare -A groups

   groups["apple"]="FRUIT"
   groups["banana"]="FRUIT"
   groups["kiwi"]="FRUIT"
   groups["melon"]="FRUIT"

   groups["radish"]="VEGETABLE"
   groups["lettuce"]="VEGETABLE"
   groups["potato"]="VEGETABLE"

   groups["blue"]="COLOR"
   groups["red"]="COLOR"
   groups["yellow"]="COLOR"
   groups["green"]="COLOR"
   groups["brown"]="COLOR"

   MY_CHOICE="kiwi"
   MY_CHOICE_GROUP=${groups[$MY_CHOICE]}

   echo $MY_CHOICE: $MY_CHOICE_GROUP
   ```

Comment: +1 for two solutions, though would be nice to mention that second one is `bash` version 4 or later only.

Answer (score 1):

Only shortening a bit @sehe's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A groups
mkaso() { val="$1"; shift; for key in "$@"; do groups["$key"]="$val"; done; }

mkaso FRUIT apple banana kiwi melon
mkaso VEGETABLE radish lettuce potato
mkaso COLOR blue red yellow green brown
#declare -p groups

MY_CHOICE="kiwi"
MY_CHOICE_GROUP=${groups[$MY_CHOICE]}
echo $MY_CHOICE: $MY_CHOICE_GROUP
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FRUIT="apple banana kiwi melon"
VEGETABLE="radish lettuce potato"
COLOR="blue red yellow green brown"

MY_CHOICE="kiwi"

for group in VEGETABLE COLOR FRUIT
do
    if [[ ${!group} == *${MY_CHOICE}* ]]; then
        MY_CHOICE_GROUP=$group
        break
    fi
done

echo $MY_CHOICE_GROUP
```

Comment: +1 for using variable indirection, but finish the job in bash: `if [[ ${!group} == *${MY_CHOICE}* ]]; ...`